# MySQL REGEXP case sensitivity when using CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Usually REGEXP is case insensitive, e.g.:

```
mysql> select count(*) from data_tool where name regexp 'CD';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       22 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from data_tool where name regexp 'cd';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       22 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it seems that when I use in a concat it becomes case sensitive, e.g.:

```
mysql> select count(*) from data_tool where concat_ws('.',name,id) regexp 'cd';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from data_tool where concat_ws('.',name,id) regexp 'CD';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       22 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What actual issue are you trying to solve? `REGEXP` is almost always a wrong solution.

Comment: @Martin Wow, that's a bold assertion!

Comment: Also: `The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal. `

Comment: This was just a simplified example. The actual application takes a search field from a user that supports full reg exp, so in my case it is the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

So one of your CONCAT strings is binary.

Therefore if it works on your `name` column this implies that the column is a standard string (`_ci`), but then appending the `id` column which I *assume* is a numeric value, this is a binary column so causes the REGEXP to be case sensitive.

**Solution:**

> but in the real case I am concating a char and an int.

[CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) your numeric column as a case insensitive string:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM data_tool WHERE 
 concat_ws('.',name,CAST(id AS CHAR)) REGEXP 'cd';
```

<strike>You *might* also need to double check that your default table Collation ends in `_ci` indicating the default string column values are case insensitive.</strike>
Please note you **can't** cast an *Int* to a *Varchar* type.

I hope that helps.

If not, please edit your question and output your Table structure details (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) so we can see how it's made. Cheers

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using `utf8_general_ci` (case insensitive) collation in the column `name`. So when you concatenate with the `id` column (numeric ?) it is implicitly converted to a case sensitive collation like `utf8_bin`.

What is the collation of the name and id columns?

Comment: Ah, I think that might be the issue. My post was just an example, but in the real case I am concating a char and an int. I will try converting the int to a char.

Comment: why does this get a -1? this is pretty close to the right answer.